# Cannot locate xindy module for language dutch in codepage utf8?

Tags: xindy

Texmaker executes xindy as:

```
xindy -I xindy -L dutch -M test -C utf8 -t test.glg -o test.gls test.glo
```

This gives the following error message:

```
Cannot locate xindy module for language dutch in codepage utf8
```

When I manually enter:

```
xindy -I xindy -M test -t test.glg -o test.gls test.glo
```

All works correctly, and glossary entries show up, as expected.

LaTeX file test.tex:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage[automake,xindy={language=dutch,codepage=utf8}]{glossaries}

\newglossaryentry{John Lennon}{
name={John Lennon},
sort={John Lennon},
description={A Beatle}}

\newglossaryentry{Paul McCartney}{
name={Paul McCartney},
sort={Paul McCartney},
description={Another Beatle}}

\newglossaryentry{Ringo Star}{
name={Ringo Star},
sort={Ringo Star},
description={Yet another Beatle}}

\newglossaryentry{George Harrison}{
name={George Harrison},
sort={George Harrison},
description={Some Beatle}}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\glsaddall
\printglossary[style=indexgroup]

\end{document}
```

Running Ubuntu 18.04.3, xindy script version: 1.18, xindy kernel version: 3.0

Cannot seem to wrap my head around this, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welkom op TeX.SE, gelukkig nieuwjaar - it seems an easy solution would be to remove the `language=dutch` part from the `xindy` options in `\usepackage{glossaries}`?

Comment: It is no solution, also a plain \usepackage[automake,xindy}]{glossaries} doesn't help.

Comment: Then maybe you can edit the rule that Texmaker uses for calling `xindy` and remove the language part - I don't know exactly how to do that because I don't use Texmaker myself but I'm sure it is possible.

Comment: Good that you solved the problem. Can you post an answer also here (in the Answer box below) explaining how you solved the problem? That could help future visitors to the site that have the same problem.

Comment: I got this sorted out, thanks to Rainer on <https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=33169&p=111622&sid=5a702c5792e1e00236a526205724245f#p111618>.  Xindy offers two variants for Dutch spelling, where 'ij' is sorted differently---as 'ij' or as 'y'. The code becomes \usepackage[automake,xindy={language=dutch,codepage=ij-as-y-utf8}]{glossaries}

Comment: Thanks, however this is not the answer box, it is the comment box. Can you put the solution as a 'real' anwer (the big text box at the bottom of the page)?

Comment: Aha. Oho. Thanks for your apt suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Xindy offers two variants for Dutch spelling, where 'ij' is sorted differently---as 'ij' or as 'y'. However, there is no default, so you have to explicitly pick your flavour, by using
`\usepackage[automake,xindy={language=dutch,codepage=ij-as-y-utf8}]{glossaries}`
or
`\usepackage[automake,xindy={language=dutch,codepage=ij-as-ij-utf8}]{glossaries}`.

(kudos to Rainer on [LaTeX Community](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=33169&sid=ac5e3df56d7fbf2d8cb7c6ee46c8d8dd))