# Cannot locate xindy module for language german in codepage latin

Tags: xindy

Newly I received the above message as I compiled one of my old documents (last year it compiled without errors). I use `TeXnicCenter x64` with following arguments

[image: TeXnicCenter]

I also found the same messages for [british](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/447659/cannot-locate-xindy-module-for-language-british-in-codepage-utf8), [dutch](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/523069/cannot-locate-xindy-module-for-language-dutch-in-codepage-utf8) and [persian](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/219817/error-cannot-locate-xindy-module-for-language-persian-in-codepage-utf8-in-maki), but I'd never used the commandline commands, because `TeXnicCenter` does it alone.

If I compile this MWE:

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{babel,makeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

  Test\index{Test}.
  \printindex

\end{document}
```

I receive the above message. What do I wrong?

Thank you for your help and effort in advance!

Comment: Try with the options `-L german-duden -C utf8`  (but xindy is a pain, consider to try xindex or so).

Comment: Hello @UlrikeFischer! Thank you for your comment! It helped! Can you please explain, why xindy is a pain and why should one use xindex?

Comment: well it is not maintained, documentation is missing, it fails if folder names contains non-ascii, its search pathes are non-standard. That makes it quite hard to debug it  something doesn't work.